# Как получить ссылку произвольной таксономии в меню административной панели WP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть произвольная таксономия `category` с категориями товаров. У нее есть дочерние категории, у которых тоже есть дочерние и т.д. Вопрос заключается в том, как получить именно ссылку на таксономию `category` при создании меню WP. Можно сослаться на определенные категории, но мне нужен именно родитель.
Пробовал через шаблон, но при переходе на категории этой таксономии перекидывает на `archive.php` - такой вариант не устраивает.
Буду признателен любым вариантам или костылям, но желательно не прибегать к использованию плагинов, хотя и такие варианты рассмотрю.

```
register_taxonomy( 'products-cat', [ 'product' ], [
        'label'                 => '',
        'labels'                => [
            'name'              => 'Категории',
            'singular_name'     => 'Категория',
            'search_items'      => 'Найти категорию',
            'all_items'         => 'Все категории',
            'view_item '        => 'Посмотреть категорию',
            'edit_item'         => 'Редактировать категорию',
            'update_item'       => 'Обновить категорию',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Добавить новую категорию',
            'new_item_name'     => 'Новое название категории',
            'menu_name'         => 'Категории',
            'back_to_items'     => '← Вернуться к категориям',
        ],
        'description'           => '',
        'public'                => true,
        'hierarchical'          => true,

        'rewrite'               => true,
        'capabilities'          => [],
        'meta_box_cb'           => null,
        'show_admin_column'     => false,
        'show_in_rest'          => null,
        'rest_base'             => null,
    ] );
```

Comment: 1. Кастомная таксономия не может называться `category`. См https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms. 2. Где код создания кастомной такчономии?

Comment: Название я условно написал. Код добавил

Comment: Ты просто мастер давать названия терминам :). Как и написания *обрывков* кода. В общем, если всё сделать правильно, то в меню всё будет. Ты скорее всего не включил вывод таксонимии на странице меню.

Comment: А где подключать вывод таксономии? То что ты говоришь похоже на аргумент ```public```. Если что-то другое, то объясни )

Comment: Я не сказал "подключать". Я сказал "включать". Как-то так https://i.imgur.com/O2C7GvR.jpeg

Comment: Я не использую ВууКомерс. Да и дело не в категориях, там по сути может быть что угодно, например таксономия "машины", а внутри нее марки машин (категории). Мне нужно, чтобы в меню была ссылка на таксономию "машины", а не на марки

Comment: WC тут не причём. Там будут любые сознанные типы контент и таксономи.

Comment: Чекбокса таксономии у меня нет, есть только рубрики - они отмечены. Даже если все чекбоксы выбрать, то ситуация не меняется. Те 2, что ты выделил выше на фото, добавляются при использовании WC. Их нет без этого плагина

Comment: Ещё раз: если кастомные сущности сделаны правильно - они там появятся .

Comment: Есть ли пример кода правильно сделанных сущностей?

Comment: В документации правильно. Вот я по-быстрячку накидал - вся само в меню появилось, даже не пришлось включать. https://i.imgur.com/aI1CfgU.jpeg Вот генератор, можешь сгенерировать https://generatewp.com/. Но прежде - читать документацию.